# Retrieving data from excel into outlook using HTML table

Tags: html, vba, excel, outlook

Fairly new to VBA here. I'm attempting to write a piece of VBA that will essentially copy some data from an already open excel file and paste it into a forwarded email in HTML formatting. Creating the email is working fine, the problem is it seems to get stuck in an endless loop when retrieving the data from excel. It gets stuck on the line str = str & "" & c.Value & ""
It will clear through the first for r loop, but then gets stuck repeating on the second.

Here's the code:

```
Function GetExcelData() As String

    Dim OrderColumn As Range, OrderRow As Range, r As Range, c As Range
    Dim str As String
    Dim xl As Excel.Application
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    'Dim rn As Excel.Range

    Set xl = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    Set wb = xl.Workbooks("Book1")
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)

    ws.Activate
    Set OrderColumn = ws.Range("A1", ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown))

    str = "<table>"

    For Each r In OrderColumn
        str = str & "<tr>"

        Set OrderRow = ws.Range(r, r.End(xlToRight))

        For Each c In OrderRow

            str = str & "<td>" & c.Value & "</td>"

        Next c

        str = str & "</tr>"
    Next r
    str = str & "</table>"
    GetExcelData = str    
End Function
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'd need to see your actual data to be sure, but I'm guessing that the row that is being processed had no data in it or only data in `OrderColumn` and the `OrderRow` range contains all columns in the sheet.  Also, I don't see any Debugging code in the function.  Have you tried dumping the ranges to the console during the loop to see if the ranges are correct?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of composing an HTML markup for the Excel range you may consider using the Word object model for getting the job done. The WordEditor property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Document class from the Word object model. See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.